# Creating Manual Journals on UI allows more accounts than through the API

Tags: xero-api

I can create a manual journal through the UI using System Accounts, like "820 - Realized Currency Gains", however when I try the exact same manual journal via the API, I get the error message: "Account code '820' is not a valid code for this document."

Is there a reason the UI allows these but the API does not?

I was expecting to be able to create the same manual journals via the API as I do with the UI.

Comment: I have the same issue FWIW. I believe it's because they're [system accounts](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/accounting/manualjournals): "There are a few accounts that you can't use when entering manual journals in Xero. These include system accounts (accounts receivable, accounts payable & retained earnings) and bank accounts."